# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input marker does not start with input path

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, databricks

Getting this error in Databricks with the following code. Can anyone explain what the error means?

```
df.writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_LOCATION) \
  .trigger(once=True) \
  .start(DELTA_FILE_LOCATION)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input marker does not start with input path!
```

Comment: can you add more details on that? How do you get the input stream?

Comment: also what DBR version

Comment: also what are the values for variables CHECKPOINT_LOCATION AND DELTA_FILE_LOCATION to see if you are assigning it in proper way..

Comment: Driver: r4.xlarge, Workers: r4.xlarge, 8 workers, On-Demand and Spot, fall back to On-Demand, 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

Comment: CHECKPOINT_LOCATION and DELTA_FILE_LOCATION are s3 buckets via s3a protocol. I'm not going to post the bucket names for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `.option("cloudFiles.useIncrementalListing", False)`

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-s3.html

Comment: Do you know why this resolved the issue? Were the input files not in lexical order?
You're now doing a full directory scan on every execution, is that scalable for you?

Comment: @englishteeth Good call, you're right, adding this setting is terrible for scalability, Unfortunately, the files do not arrive in lexical order. I've since switched to file notification mode.